# My rect collision isn't working with my classes

Tags: pygame, collision-detection

The Problem im having is i cant get my Enemy class to work with the Cubeplayer rect in the Cube class

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

Sound_Using_TP = pygame.mixer.Sound("Game imag/teleport.wav")
Sound_Get_Item_1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Game imag/power_up_collect.wav")

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Cube game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
TP_staffX = 500
TP_staffY = 500
TP_usage = 0
PhoX = 100
PhoY = -200
FPS = 60
Cube_Vel = 4
HP = 3

CubeX = 600
CubeY = 400

enemyX = 400
enemyY = 100

TP_staff = pygame.image.load("Game imag/TP staff.png")
TP_staff_rect = TP_staff.get_rect(center=(randint(100, 600), (randint(100, 700))))

TP_usage_Stat_Font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
TP_usage_Stat = TP_usage_Stat_Font.render(f"TP usages: {TP_usage}", False, "white")

Cube_player = pygame.image.load("Game imag/Cube.png")
Cube_player_rect = Cube_player.get_rect(center=(CubeX, CubeY))

enemy = pygame.image.load("Game imag/enemeycube.png")


class Cube:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.CubeplayerX = x
        self.CubeplayerY = y
        self.Cubeimage = pygame.image.load("Game imag/Cube.png")
        self.Cuberect = self.Cubeimage.get_rect(center=(self.CubeplayerX, self.CubeplayerY))

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.Cubeimage, self.Cuberect)



class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.EnemyX = x
        self.EnemyY = y
        self.Enemyimage = pygame.image.load("Game imag/enemeycube.png")
        self.Enemy_rect = self.Enemyimage.get_rect(center=(self.EnemyX, self.EnemyY))

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.Enemyimage, self.Enemy_rect)

    def Collisions(self):
        if self.Enemy_rect(self.Cuberect):
            screen.fill((255, 0, 0))


# Timer
obstacle_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(obstacle_timer, 2000)
game_on = True


def draw_text(text, color, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
    text = font.render(text, False, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(600, 50))
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)


while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    enemy = Enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    cube = Cube(CubeX, CubeY)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(TP_staff, TP_staff_rect)
    draw_text(f"TP usages: {TP_usage}", "white", 30, 500, 500)
    cube.draw(screen)

    if event.type == obstacle_timer:
        enemyX = 400
        enemyY = 100
        enemy.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
    enemy.draw(screen)
    enemy.Collisions()
    enemyY += 3
    if Cube_player_rect.colliderect(TP_staff_rect):
        TP_usage += 1
        print(TP_usage)
        TP_staff_rect = TP_staff.get_rect(center=(999, 999))
        Sound_Get_Item_1.play()
        screen.blit(TP_staff, TP_staff_rect)

    if TP_usage > 1:
        TP_usage = 1
        print(TP_usage)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and CubeX - Cube_Vel > 0:
        CubeX -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and CubeX + Cube_Vel < WIDTH:
        CubeX += Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and CubeY - Cube_Vel > 0:
        CubeY -= Cube_Vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and CubeY + Cube_Vel < HEIGHT:
        CubeY += Cube_Vel

    pressed_keys = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage > 0:
        TP_usage -= 1
        print(TP_usage)
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        CubeX = mx
        CubeY = my
        Sound_Using_TP.play()
    if (pressed_keys[0]) and TP_usage < 0:
        pass

    pygame.display.update()
```

Everytime I run my code it gives me a AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'Cuberect' error. i've tired using globe but that didn't work and i don't know a other way to get my collision work.

and this is the stack trace error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fayro\PycharmProjects\Cube game\Cube game.py", line 104, in <module>
    enemy.Collisions()
  File "C:\Users\fayro\PycharmProjects\Cube game\Cube game.py", line 66, in Collisions
    if self.Enemy_rect(self.Cuberect):
AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'Cuberect'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're trying to access the attribute `Cuberect`, which is not an attribute of `Enemy`. `Enemy` has many other attributes but not `Cuberect`. The error message gives you the exact line and stack trace so I'm not going to look over all this code to find where the error occurs. Instead, you should post the full error message inside a code block. Optimally, you should create a [mre]. For example, is the sound necessary in the code for the error to appear? If not, remove it.

Comment: oh ok thxs and ill show the lines of code were the error is happening

Comment: No, you need to provide the stack trace. The full error that occurs. It tells you the exact line and exactly which functions that were called when the error happened.

Comment: oh ok sorry i didn't know what you meant by stack trace

Comment: You're trying to access `self.Cuberect` in the `Enemy`, but it doesn't have any `Cuberect`. I'm guessing you want to pass in a `cube` into the method `Collision` as a parameter.

Comment: yeah but i cant find a way to make the Enemy class work with Cuberect

Comment: You need to pass it into the method, just like you do with your method `draw`. In `draw` you've got your enemy class to work with the screen

Comment: oh ok thxs a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the Cuberect attribute in the Enemy class. However, this attribute is only available in the Cube class. You need to pass the Cuberect attribute somehow to the Enemy class.

The best way to do this would be an argument within the *Collision* function. You also need to change the if statement a little bit, because it would throw an error anyway. Take a look at this new Collisions function:

```
def Collisions(self, test_object):
    if self.Enemy_rect.colliderect(test_object.Cuberect):
        screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
```

You're calling the `colliderect` function to test wether two rect objects collide. Also, you can now access the Cuberect attribute, as long as the test_object that you passed to the function has that attribute within its class definition.

To make it work, you will need to update the line where you call the Collision function as well to:

```
enemy.Collisions(cube)
```